# package arydshln breaks package vhistory

Tags: option-clash

It seems to me that the package `arydshln` breaks the package `vhistory`.

Here is a MWE from the `vhistory` [CTAN documentation page](https://ctan.org/pkg/vhistory?lang=en):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{vhistory, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{versionhistory}
 \vhEntry{1.0}{22.01.04}{AA}{created}
 \vhEntry{1.1}{23.01.04}{DP|JPW}{correction}
 \vhEntry{1.2}{03.02.04}{DP|JPW}{revised after review}
\end{versionhistory}

\end{document}
```

The output is as expected:

[image]

However, if you also load the package `arydshln`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{vhistory, hyperref}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{versionhistory}
 \vhEntry{1.0}{22.01.04}{AA}{created}
 \vhEntry{1.1}{23.01.04}{DP|JPW}{correction}
 \vhEntry{1.2}{03.02.04}{DP|JPW}{revised after review}
\end{versionhistory}

\end{document}
```

The output becomes:

[image]

Any idea why this happens? Is there a way to prevent this problem, so that the functionality of both packages can be preserved? If not, is there an alternative package to `arydshln`?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The `arydshln` package has often conflicted with other tabular packages (and `vhistory` loads `ltxtable` which loads `longtable` and `tabularx`). I thought these issues had been resolved, but maybe not. Loading `arydshln` before `vhistory` solves the problem, but it remains to be seen whether that breaks any specific `arydshln` functionality (although it might not.)

Comment: @alanmunn Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arydshln` package has often conflicted with other tabular packages (and `vhistory` loads `ltxtable` which loads `longtable` and `tabularx`). I thought these issues had been resolved, but maybe not. Loading `arydshln` before `vhistory` solves the problem, but it remains to be seen whether that breaks any specific `arydshln` functionality (although it might not.)

I've added this as an answer, since it appears to work, but if this breaks `arydshln` by doing so, then please comment on the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln} % load before vhistory

\usepackage{vhistory, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{versionhistory}
 \vhEntry{1.0}{22.01.04}{AA}{created}
 \vhEntry{1.1}{23.01.04}{DP|JPW}{correction}
 \vhEntry{1.2}{03.02.04}{DP|JPW}{revised after review}
\end{versionhistory}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The above solution by @alanmunn works. The only thing that needs to be kept in mind is that the `arydshln` package also needs to be loaded before all tabular packages such as `tabularx`, `longtable` and so on. Otherwise an error is generated.